# Date output to the command line

Tags: java, date

Please tell me how to display the date in the console in the Java programming language. For example, in the code I specify:
`Date date = new Date(2019-09-23)`

Then the program displays to the console what I entered in the program code
2019-09-23

Comment: Please specify your question. Do you really want to use a Date or do you just want to output the input so you may use a String instead of Date. Also your given code snippet would not work as `2019-09-23` is no valid data type in Java. To simply output something to the command line you should use `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

If I understand you correctly, you are after:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.SEPTEMBER, 23);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output in the console from these two lines is:

> 2019-09-23

I recommend you don’t use the `Date` class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead I am using and recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the value you can directly print using `System.out.println()`

```
System.out.println("2019-09-23");
```

If you want to assign to String variable

```
String date = "2019-09-23";
System.out.println(date);
```

If you really want to use Date then try this

```
try {
    String input = "2019-09-23";

    // convert String to Date
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = format.parse(input);

    // convert Date to String
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```